# Getting below issue while fetching private repositories from GitHub with Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have added credentials to the jenkins for GItHub account.
I was able to checkout code from github desktop.
But with Jenkins, I am getting below error with the private repositories.
[image: Jenkins Console Output]

Comment: Please do not include images of textual output, but include the textual output itself in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think size of the repo is large in size and it is taking more than 10 mins to clone, as the threshold timeout to clone is 10 mins. From Advanced Behaviors of Git Scm section increase the timeout to larger value.

Comment: Can you tell how to increase the time limit then.

And also for testing I tried a small repo, but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got root cause for the issue mentioned above.

When the Jenkins is trying to trigger git.exe to download the content from github.THe git is trying to access git credential manager.

So as a fix suggested by some friend in Facebook, I am uncheking the "Git Credential Manager" while installing the git.
Then it is working!!!

Answer (score 0):

For detailed description you can visit below link:
https://devopsdiaryblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/06/jenkins-issue-with-fetching-github-data/